# Como fazer uma operação condicional em que o resultado de "A" depende de "B" para uma condição e "B" depende de "A" para outra

Tags: r, dplyr

Estou desenvolvendo um indicador chamado balanço hídrico climatológico normal, ele serve para mensurar a quantidade de água que entra e que sai de um determinado solo, durante um determinado período.

O meu balanço hídrico utiliza a metodologia de thornthwaite & Matter 1955, que utiliza como dados primários apenas dados de temperatura e precipitação para produzir todas as outras variáveis.

O que um balanço hídrico BASICAMENTE necessita conter?
**Mes** <- Cada mês do ano;
**Tc** <- média das temperaturas compensadas em todos os meses do ano (celsius);
**P** <- precipitação (mm) total de cada mes do ano;
**ETP** <- Evapotranspiração potencial, que é a capacidade de transferência pela evaporação natural da água no solo para a atmosfera (mm);
**P-ETP** <- o balanço entre o quanto chove e o quanto evapora para a atmosfera(mm);
**CAD** <- Capacidade disponível (mm), é o quanto de água o solo consegue absorver devido ás suas características físicas;
**NAC** <-negativo acumulado (mm), é o "prejuízo" entre a entrada e a saída de água do solo;
**ARM** <- representa a quantidade de água que o solo pode reter, em tese, num determinado período.

Sabendo disso, agora vou ao que interessa. O cálculo do **NAC** e do **ARM** são condicionais um ao outro e ao **P-ETP** de forma que são expressas da seguinte maneira.

Legenda:
mp = Mês anterior,
exp= exponencial do número, ln = log do número

CONDIÇÃO 1 <- Se (P-ETP) < 0, primeiro se calcula o NAC,depois o NRM, fica assim:  **NAC = NACmp + (P-ETP)**, posteriormente se calcula o **ARM** que é expresso pela fórmula **ARM = CAD * exp(NAC/CAD)**

CONDIÇÃO 2 <- Se (P-ETP) >= 0, primeiro se calcula o NRM depois o NAC, fica assim: **ARM = ARMmp + (P-ETP)**, após isso, o se calcula **NAC = CAD * ln(ARM/CAD)**

Em resumo, quando P-ETP é negativo, primeiro se processa o NAC e depois o ARM,
quando P-ETP é positivo, primeiro se processa o ARM depois o NAC.

Aí vem o problema, como eu ensino o R a fazer esse tipo de condicionamento? no EXCEL eu consigo estabelecer essa condição.

Vou montar um data frame exemplo:

```r
library(dplyr)  

CAD <- 100   
MES <- c("jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez")  
Tc <- c(25, 23, 25, 26, 27, 23, 23, 25, 27, 29, 29, 26)  
P <- c(100, 200, 300, 100, 20, 40, 50, 100, 120, 10, 30, 100)  
ETP <- c(120, 150, 122, 140, 150, 160, 180, 100, 90, 90, 80, 70)   
"P - ETP" <- P - ETP   

BALANCO_TESTE <- tibble(MES, CAD, Tc, P, ETP, P-ETP)
```

Já tentei gerar a coluna NAC e ARM com `case_when()`, contudo, como ambas são interdependentes, eu não tô conseguindo escrever esse *loop*.

Comment: A não ser que eu tenha entendido errado, não vejo como calcular o primeiro valor de NAC ou ARM. Sem perda de generalidade, suponha que P-ETP < 0. Assim, `NAC_fev = NAC_jan + (P-ETP)` e `ARM_fev = CAD * exp(NAC_fev/CAD)`. Mas onde está `NAC_jan` no conjunto de dados fornecido? Ele precisa ser inicializado de algum forma, creio eu.

Comment: Bom dia, Marcus. Você está correto, esqueci de acrescentar que o NAC_jan = 0 porque ele é o ponto de partida, depois a fórmula segue o descrito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz na forma mais simples para interpretação da análise de condições.

```
library(dplyr)  

CAD <- 100   
MES <- c("jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez")  
Tc <- c(25, 23, 25, 26, 27, 23, 23, 25, 27, 29, 29, 26)  
P <- c(100, 200, 300, 100, 20, 40, 50, 100, 120, 10, 30, 100)  
ETP <- c(120, 150, 122, 140, 150, 160, 180, 100, 90, 90, 80, 70)   
"P - ETP" <- P - ETP   

BALANCO_TESTE <- tibble(MES, CAD, Tc, P, ETP, P-ETP)

BALANCO_TESTE$NAC <- NA
BALANCO_TESTE$ARM <- NA
BALANCO_TESTE$condicao <- ""

for(i in 1:dim(BALANCO_TESTE)[1]){
  if(BALANCO_TESTE[i, "P - ETP"] < 0){
    BALANCO_TESTE$NAC[i] = ifelse(i == 1, 0, BALANCO_TESTE$NAC[i-1]) + BALANCO_TESTE$`P - ETP`[i]
    BALANCO_TESTE$ARM[i] = BALANCO_TESTE$CAD[i] * exp(BALANCO_TESTE$NAC[i]/BALANCO_TESTE$CAD[i])
    BALANCO_TESTE$condicao[i] <- "CONDIÇÃO 1"
  }
  if(BALANCO_TESTE[i, "P - ETP"] >= 0){
    BALANCO_TESTE$ARM[i] = ifelse(i == 1, 0, BALANCO_TESTE$ARM[i-1]) + BALANCO_TESTE$`P - ETP`[i]
    BALANCO_TESTE$NAC[i] = BALANCO_TESTE$CAD[i] * log(BALANCO_TESTE$ARM[i]/BALANCO_TESTE$CAD[i])
    BALANCO_TESTE$condicao[i] <- "CONDIÇÃO 2"
  }
}

> BALANCO_TESTE
# A tibble: 12 × 9
   MES     CAD    Tc     P   ETP `P - ETP`    NAC    ARM condicao  
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     
 1 jan     100    25   100   120       -20  -20    81.9  CONDIÇÃO 1
 2 fev     100    23   200   150        50   27.7 132.   CONDIÇÃO 2
 3 mar     100    25   300   122       178  113.  310.   CONDIÇÃO 2
 4 abr     100    26   100   140       -40   73.1 208.   CONDIÇÃO 1
 5 mai     100    27    20   150      -130  -56.9  56.6  CONDIÇÃO 1
 6 jun     100    23    40   160      -120 -177.   17.1  CONDIÇÃO 1
 7 jul     100    23    50   180      -130 -307.    4.65 CONDIÇÃO 1
 8 ago     100    25   100   100         0 -307.    4.65 CONDIÇÃO 2
 9 set     100    27   120    90        30 -106.   34.6  CONDIÇÃO 2
10 out     100    29    10    90       -80 -186.   15.6  CONDIÇÃO 1
11 nov     100    29    30    80       -50 -236.    9.44 CONDIÇÃO 1
12 dez     100    26   100    70        30  -93.0  39.4  CONDIÇÃO 2
```

Comment: Bom dia, amigo. Sinceramente, você é nota 1000. Muito obrigado, sua solução ajudou bastante.  Agradeço muito por compartilhar seus conhecimentos. Forte abraço!!